# How can i remove repeated values in a single column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like:

```
shops        prod_id      atv_y1   

company_b    A           56.3      
company_b    B           4.3     
company_b    C           136.3    
company_b    D           89.3
company_c    A           7.3
company_c    B           64.0 
company_c    A           34.7
```

For the purpose of plotting i would like to remove the repeated company_b/company_c values so that it takes only the first time it is referenced like below:

```
shops        prod_id      atv_y1   

company_b    A           56.3      
             B           4.3     
             C           136.3    
             D           89.3
company_c    A           7.3
             B           64.0 
             A           34.7
```

how can i do this in pandas ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to manage this within plots itself by the way. But if you really want the df transformed like you asked, then you could try something like below.
It may not be the best way, but does the job.

```
shops = df.groupby('shops').first().reset_index()['shops']
for i in shops:
    l = np.where(df['shops'] == i)[0]
    df.loc[l[1]:l[len(l)-1],'shops'] = ''
print(df)
```

prints

```
       shops prod_id  atv_y1
0  company_b       A    56.3
1                  B     4.3
2                  C   136.3
3                  D    89.3
4  company_c       A     7.3
5                  B    64.0
6                  A    34.7
```